# Grouping Items using case statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

**Problem: How can i group the table by using case statement.**

for example i have two tables.

first table

id name 
1 a
2 b
3 c

second table is

id status 
1 red
1 red
1 blue
1 red

**here's the scenario:**

- I left join id on table 1 and table 2.
- If it has the same id then it will create a case statement.

  1. If all status contains red on table 2 then [condition]
  2. if status contains red and blue the [condtion]
  3. if not on the case then [condtion]

how will i create this?

Comment: can you give examples of your condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a general approach across most/all DBMS then you can use this:

```
SELECT  t.ID,
        t.Name,
        CASE WHEN t.Red = t.Total THEN 'Only Red condition'
            WHEN t.Red > 0 AND t.Blue > 0 THEN 'Red and blue condition'
            ELSE 'Other condition'
        END AS CaseCondition
FROM    (   SELECT  Table1.ID,
                    Table1.Name,
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN Table2.Status = 'Red' THEN 1 END) AS Red,
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN Table2.Status = 'Blue' THEN 1 END) AS Blue,
                    COUNT(Table2.Status) AS Total
            FROM    Table1
                    LEFT JOIN Table2
                        ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
            GROUP BY Table1.ID, Table1.Name
        ) t
```

If your DBMS supports PIVOT (and the only possible values are red and blue) then you can use something like:

```
SELECT  ID,
        Name
        CASE WHEN pvt.Red > 0 AND pvt.Blue = 0  THEN 'Only Red condition'
            WHEN t.Red > 0 AND t.Blue > 0 THEN 'Red and blue condition'
            ELSE 'Other condition'
        END AS CaseCondition
FROM    Table1
        LEFT JOIN Table2
            ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
        PIVOT
        (   COUNT(Table2.ID)
            FOR Table2.Status IN ([Red], [Blue])
        ) pvt
```